# Cannot access bloc from a child class due to context issues?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, bloc

When I am trying to access the bloc from a child class it gives me an error

```
flutter: ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
flutter: The following assertion was thrown building Builder:
flutter:         BlocProvider.of() called with a context that does not contain a Bloc of type
flutter: TopRatedMovieBloc.
flutter:         No ancestor could be found starting from the context that was passed to
flutter: BlocProvider.of<TopRatedMovieBloc>().
flutter:
flutter:         This can happen if:
flutter:         1. The context you used comes from a widget above the BlocProvider.
flutter:         2. You used MultiBlocProvider and didn't explicity provide the BlocProvider types.
flutter:
flutter:         Good: BlocProvider<TopRatedMovieBloc>(builder: (context) => TopRatedMovieBloc())
flutter:         Bad: BlocProvider(builder: (context) => TopRatedMovieBloc()).
```

My code looks like the following:

```
**main.dart**

void main() {
  final MovieRepository movieRepository = MovieRepository(
    movieApiClient: MovieApiClient(
      httpClient: http.Client(),
    ),
  );
  BlocSupervisor.delegate = SimpleBlocDelegate();
  runApp(App(movieRepository: movieRepository),
    );
  }

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  final MovieRepository movieRepository;
  App({Key key, @required this.movieRepository})
      : assert(movieRepository != null),
        super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Infinite Scroll',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue, canvasColor: Colors.transparent),
home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  final MovieRepository movieRepository = MovieRepository(
    movieApiClient: MovieApiClient(
      httpClient: http.Client(),
    ),
  );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocBuilder<ChangeThemeBloc, ChangeThemeState>(
      builder: (context, state) {
        return Scaffold(body: Container(
            color: state.themeData.primaryColor,
            child: ListView(
              physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
              children: <Widget>[
                DiscoverMovies(
                  themeData: state.themeData,
                ),
                BlocProvider(
                  builder: (BuildContext context) =>
                      TopRatedMovieBloc(movieRepository: movieRepository),
                  child: ScrollingMovies(
                    themeData: state.themeData,
                    title: 'Top Rated',
                    api: Api.toprated,
                  ),
                ),
],
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}



class ScrollingMovies extends StatefulWidget {
  final ThemeData themeData;
  final String title;
  final Api api;
  ScrollingMovies({
    this.themeData,
    this.api,
    this.title,
  });
  @override
  _ScrollingMoviesState createState() => _ScrollingMoviesState();
}

class _ScrollingMoviesState extends State<ScrollingMovies> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    TopRatedMovieBloc _topRatedMovieBloc =
        BlocProvider.of<TopRatedMovieBloc>(context);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[])
  }
```

It gives me error on this line :

`TopRatedMovieBloc _topRatedMovieBloc = BlocProvider.of<TopRatedMovieBloc>(context);`

Can someone help me understand this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't access `context` in `initState`. 
You have some options here:
 1. move bloc usage into `build` method.
 2. override [`didChangeDependencies`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/didChangeDependencies.html) and use it there. First time it's called right after `initState` but with `context` available. It might be called multiple times if dependencies changed so if you want to do something only once - check if you haven't done it before.
 3. pass bloc through constructor

Another problem is described in original error message:

```
flutter:         Good: BlocProvider<TopRatedMovieBloc>(builder: (context) => TopRatedMovieBloc())
flutter:         Bad: BlocProvider(builder: (context) => TopRatedMovieBloc()).
```

You need to update code in `_MyHomePageState` `build` method by adding type parameter to BlocProvider, so it should look like

```
BlocProvider<TopRatedMovieBloc>(
                  builder: (BuildContext context) =>
                      TopRatedMovieBloc(movieRepository: movieRepository),
                  child: ScrollingMovies(
                    themeData: state.themeData,
                    title: 'Top Rated',
                    api: Api.toprated,
                  ),
                ),
```

Comment: I moved all bloc usage to build method but it still gives me the same error?

Comment: @user818455 I've updated my answer with additional problem solution

Comment: adding the type parameter to BlocProvider solved the issue. Thanks